# Updating a model with validations Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord, activemodel

How do I update a record in rails by making it go through all the necessary validations? As far as i know

```
record.update_attributes(update_hash)
```

will skip all the validations. 
How do i update my record without skipping the validations? I'm using Rails 3.2 by the way.

Comment: Is using record.assign_attributes(update_hash).save  the right method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails 3.2, the method `update_attributes` run all model validations, only the ***singular form*** `update_attribute` skip validations. Fortunately, in Rails 4 they deprecated the later, in favour of `update_column` ([see commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/a7f4b0a1231bf3c65db2ad4066da78c3da5ffb01)).

Docs:

- [update_attributes](https://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attributes)
- [update_attribute](https://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attribute)

Answer (score 1):

`update_attributes` itself checks for validations.
It returns false if unable to save (*due to validation errors or an erroneous query*).

Internally `update_attributes` actually calls `save` method itself which checks for validations before saving to the database.